# Ionic v4 and Angular Cannot able to get the inner text of ion-slide of loop generated slides

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, slide, ionic4, ion-slides

I am having an array displayed in `<ion-slide>` using `*ngFor` looping around a defined array:

```
status: string[] = [
  'Active',
  'Inactive',
  'Ended'
];
@ViewChild('slideWithNav') slides: IonSlides;
@ViewChild('status') slide: IonSlide;
```

And here is the html script:

```
<ion-slides class="fullWidth" [options]="slideOptsOne" #slideWithNav (ionSlideDidChange)="SlideDidChange($event)">
   <ion-slide #status *ngFor="let s of status" >
    <ion-col>
        {{s}}
    </ion-col>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

When a slide change, I need to get the value of `s`, to run a specific function.

I tried to access it using `(ionSlideDidChange)`:

```
SlideDidChange(s) {
    console.log(this.slides);
}
```

But I can't find anything related to `<ion-slide>` inner value.

I tried the following [script](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-slides-accessing-a-component-created-within-an-inner-ngfor-loop/75788/2):

```
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular'; 
import { ViewChild, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChildren('CardSlider') cardSliders: QueryList<Slides>;

onCardChanged(){ let slides= this.slides.toArray(); 
    let slider= slides[this.currentSuitIndex]; 
    this.currentCardIndex[this.currentSuitIndex] = cardSlider.getActiveIndex(); 
    console.log('Status', slider.getActiveIndex()); 
}
```

But it didn't work either. The required output, is when I am in the `Active` Slide, I need to console "Active" and run the required method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently the activated index is a promise:

```
SlideDidChange(s)
{
  this.slides.getActiveIndex().then(
     (index)=>{
       this.currentIndex = index;
    });
}
```

By using `.then()` we can get the current index, and use `SWITCH` case to case indexes and run the required methods accordingly.